# Clustering with only two variables?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to cluster my two-dimensional dataset, but I couldn't figure it out. My dataset looks like below,

```
dt<-data.frame(x=c(rnorm(10, 2,1), rnorm(10, 6,1)), categorize=c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10)))
```

I just want to plot this dataset like the graph below, if I add the third value like `c(1:nrow(dt))` does it work or what do you recommend me?

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(dt, aes(x, y=1, color = factor(categorize))) + geom_point()`?

Comment: `with(dt, plot(x, col=categorize + 1, pch=20))` using base graphics?